# Flutter Firebase upload a List of customClass

Tags: list, firebase, flutter

I want to upload a List of a custom class to the cloud firebase, but I get the error that my custom class is not a subtype of type `<dynamic>`. Does this happen because it is not possible to upload List of custom classes to firebase? Do I need to create e new collection which than works as the List or is there a other way to work around this problem?

```js
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//Class for the custom list
class CustomClass {
  int id;
  String content;

  CustomClass({this.id, this.content});

  CustomClass.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    id = data['id'];
    content = data['content'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'content': content,
    };
  }
}

//Model which I want to upload with the custom list
class CustomModel {
  String name;
  List<CustomClass> customList;

  CustomModel();

  CustomModel.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    name = data['name'];
    customList = data['customList'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'customList': customList,
    };
  }
}

//Page to upload the customModel with the customList
class UploadPage extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomModel _customModel = CustomModel();
  List<CustomClass> _customList = [CustomClass(id: 1, content: 'UserContent')];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Upload'),
          onPressed: () async {
            _customModel.name = 'UserName';
            _customModel.customList = _customList;
            await Firestore.instance
                .collection('CustomClass')
                .add(_customModel.toMap());
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can upload any type of custom class to Firebase. You just have to convert it in `json` format or `Map<String, dynamic>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dart: convert` to convert your model object into json format i.e `Map` which you can upload to Firebase.

For this, I have renamed your `toMap` method to `toJson` & `fromMap` methods to `fromJson`. Also, I have added `factory` keyword before `fromJson` methods.

You should also override the `toString` method to print your objects for testing/debugging.

Your code should look something like this:

```
//Class for the custom list
class CustomClass {
  int id;
  String content;

  CustomClass({this.id, this.content});

  factory CustomClass.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    return CustomClass(
      id: data['id'],
      content: data['content'],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'content': content,
    };
  }
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${const JsonEncoder.withIndent(' ').convert(this)}';
  }
}

//Model wich I want to upload with the custom list
class CustomModel {
  String name;
  List<CustomClass> customList;

  CustomModel({
    this.name,
    this.customList,
  });

  factory CustomModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    List<dynamic> list = data['customList'] ?? [];

    final customList = list.map((e) => CustomClass.fromJson(e)).toList();

    return CustomModel(
      name: data['name'],
      customList: customList,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'name': name,
      'customList': customList?.map((e) => e.toJson())?.toList(),
    };
  }
  
  @override
  String toString() {
    return '${const JsonEncoder.withIndent(' ').convert(this)}';
  }
}

// Your build method:
CustomModel _customModel = CustomModel();
  List<CustomClass> _customList = [CustomClass(id: 1, content: 'UserContent')];

@override
Widget build(BuilContext context) {
return Scaffold(
      body: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Upload'),
          onPressed: () async {
            _customModel.name = 'UserName';
            _customModel.customList = _customList;
            await Firestore.instance
                .collection('CustomClass')
                .add(_customModel.toJson());
          }),
    );
}
```

Comment: I get the error: Invalid argument: Instance of 'CustomClass'). on the line where the Model gets uploaded

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check the `toJson` method in `CustomModel` class. Now, you will not get that error.

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi how do I get & parse the data from Firebase now inside a ListView.builder?